# can anyone help me how to pass the results of separately to other page when schedule is clicked

Tags: php, mysql

1.

```
 <?php
    $sql = "(SELECT id,Firstname, Lastname, MI, Course, Date_Enrolled FROM  listofstudents )";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows > 0){ // build a table to show results
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['Firstname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['Lastname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['MI'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['Course'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['Date_Enrolled'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'> <a href='schedule.php?name=".$row['Firstname']."lastname=". $row['Lastname'] . " mi=". $row['MI'] ."'>Schedule</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }   
    } else{
        echo "No rows returned.";
    }
?>
```

1. List item

Comment: read this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hint: Populate `$_GET` with a variable of some kind by making a query string.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data in url witch is not safe 
You can send tha ID and on the requested page you can the get the row by sql query.